# Making an LED lamp smart with IKEA and an SSR - LED is flickering when SSR is on/off

Tags: led, solid-state-relay

I have an IKEA LED lamp, that can't be used with a remote control. I've decided to make a circuit with an SSR, where the SSR is toggled on and off with a 10W IKEA LED driver that can be turned on by a remote.

I've made a circuit, hoped to get it working properly, but the SSR leaks enough to flicker the lamp. After researching online, I've found out that SSRs are leaking enough current to light LEDs up, even when they're off. Solution would be to add a light bulb, like a Christmas light (don't have any) or some sort of load (resistor?).

I've connected 1W resistors (100kOhm/47kOhm/10kOhms) both in series and parallel (not at the same time) to the lamp, nothing fixed the flickering.

The thing that's bothering me the most is that LEDs with SSRs are only flickering when the SSR is off. With my circuit, the light flickers even when the SSR is turned on. Can someone offer a solution to fix this issue?

I've made a schematic in Paint about my circuit, sorry for the symbols, haven't used them in 3 years, I think I've forgotten them.
[image: Circuit for the LED Light]

Stuff I used:

[SSR from Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B071HP9NJD/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

[IKEA TRÅDFRI LED Driver](https://www.ikea.com/at/de/p/tradfri-treiber-fuer-fernbedienung-grau-50356187/)

[IKEA TRÅDFRI Remote](https://www.ikea.com/at/de/p/tradfri-kabelloser-dimmer-weiss-70408595/)

[IKEA VÅTHULT LED Lamp](https://www.ikea.com/at/de/p/vathult-schrank-spiegelleuchte-led-aluminiumfarben-40467548/)

Comment: Why did you chose this SSR? Were you aware that it is rated for 40 amperes? That is a seriously heavy-duty SSR.  This SSR specification says "Power off discharge current: <2mA" - I interpret that to mean, it could be leaking as much as 1.99 mA. The load you are using is drawing very much less power and current, a tiny fraction (~ 35 mA at 230VAC). So 1.99mA is only ~6% of the lamp's nominal current draw but certainly could be enough to produce visible effect from that LED lamp.

Comment: Both too high leakage current and too high hold current?

Comment: You almost certainly can't drive an SSR with an LED driver like that. The LED driver wants to 'see' what looks like a normal LED load, and the SSR doesn't give it that. What *might* help is if you put something like a 68R 1W resistor in parallel with the SSR input so that the LED driver sees a bit of a load there, rather than just the SSR alone. Note that this resistor *will* get pretty warm though...

Comment: @RichS I thought power off discharge current means that it discharges some current while powering off.

Comment: @winny goo to know, I'm gonna look for a better SSR

Comment: @brhans I don't think that I have a problem with the LED driver, it successfully turns on and off the SSR. The SSR output is the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the correct track, by putting a resistor across (in parallel with) the LED lamp. But 10k ohms was not low enough, it seems.  Try 5k ohms. The idea is, when the SSR is Off, to draw away more of this "leakage current" in to the resistor, and away from the LED lamp. In order for the lamp to be off, it probably has to see only a very low voltage across it, like 10 volts (I am guessing). If the SSR Off leakage is 2 mA, then your resistor would need be less than 10V / 2mA = 5000 ohms.  The resistor would also need a power rating of at least (230 V ^ 2) / 5000 = 11 watts (20 watts to be practical and safe).  However, the energy-saving answer would be to use a better SSR for this: a model that does not leak so much current!

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna buy a better one, I don't think that the discharge current is right, if I have the chance, I'll measure it, but more expensive products have an even higher discharge current.

Comment: Just measured everything. When the SSR is turned on, it didn't get enough power from the LED drive. The drive was set to the lowest setting, increasing the power fixed the flickering.

When the SSR is off, it leaks 7.3mAmps, not even close to the one specified by the vendor.

I'm gonna buy a better, non-shady SSR. :)